# LastRow in excel function changes based on value in cell without using vba

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following function in excel:

```
=SUMIF($H$2:$H$500;CONCATENATE(N$1;$K$1;$K2;$M$1;$M2);$C$2:$C$500)
```

In this instance it's in column N row 2. I have a macro that pulls this function down the column.

In this function it considers everything from cell H2 to H500

> $H$2:$H$500

and C2 to C500

> $C$2:$C$500

C500 & H500 = LastRow, I manually entered this number, but when the amount of entries exceed this number, they do not get counted and the outcome is incorrect.

I have a cell R2 that contains a number, 1, and it will change according to the LastRow I have figured out from another file. This will update automatically.

I want the number 500, which is now a static number that I typed, to change according to the number (value) in cell R2. To make it more flexible.

If the value in cell R2 changes from 1 to 300, then the number 500 in this example, needs to change to this 300 from cell R2.
I know that when the change to this function is made that it would not be 500 but 1, because the number in cell R2 is 1 and not 500.

It would be something like:

```
=SUMIF($H$2:$H$**R2**;CONCATENATE(N$1;$K$1;$K2;$M$1;$M2);$C$2:$C$**R2**)
```

I tried selecting the cell R2 when I selected the $500 in the function but it would instead look at the range between H2 and R2 as a selection, but this is not what I want.

I want it to look still at only the H column, just more or less rows, which is defined by the value in R2.

I hope somebody has a solution for this.

My thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use INDIRECT() to build addresses.

```
=SUMIF(INDIRECT("$H$2:$H$" & TEXT($R$2, "#####"));CONCATENATE(N$1;$K$1;$K2;$M$1;$M2);INDIRECT("$H$2:$H$" & TEXT($R$2, "#####"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `OFFSET` function to give you what you wish. `OFFSET` returns a range based on the parameters you've chosen. In this case you can supply `OFFSET` with the number of rows to return based on your cell `R2`.

There's a good example [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324991) from Microsoft so I won't repeat it here.

Your formula then becomes:

```
=SUMIF(OFFSET(Sheet1!$H$2;0;0;Sheet1!$R$2-1;1);CONCATENATE(N$1;$K$1;$K2;$M$1;$M2);OFFSET(Sheet1!$C$2;0;0;Sheet1!$R$2-1;1))
```

Bear in mind that you are still hard-coding the start of the rows to H2 and C2 respectively, therefore if these move, you will need to ensure that the adjustment (i.e the `-1` in the part `Sheet1!$R$2-1`) is correct for your case.